# A python code for converting the longitude of a planet into 360 degree format

Tags: python, dictionary

It is the usual practice to mention the longitude of the planet
by it's rasi position and the degrees.

Example:  Sun in virgo 23 degrees.  To convert this into a 360 format you have to add 150 degree the starting point of virgo.  Adding the 23 to 150 gives 173 degrees.

I have the dictionary:

```
RasiDegree={"Aries":0,"Tarus":30,"Gemini":60,"Cancer":90,"Leo":120,
```

"Virgo":150,"Libra":180,"Scorpio":210,"Sagitarius":240,"Capricorn":270,"Aquarius":300,"Pisces":330}

```
for rasi,degree in RasiDegree.items():
    print(rasi, degree)
```

the print out comes out correctly.
To access any particular rasi, my code is `print(RasiDegree["rasi"])`

So far so good.  How do I write the python prograame to calculate the above.
I tried to get the user input for the rasi and the degree.  I am stuck.  Should I write a function?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Python input() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

Comment: firstly, your "code" above should be `print(RasiDegree[rasi])` -- note that `rasi` is _variable_ and should not be in quotes.  secondly, it is unclear to me what you're asking for:  could you edit your question above and perhaps give an example of input / output desired.  also, present your attempt and errors, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Use below function. This function takes rasi name and degree by user as input and return in 360 fomat.

```
def calculate():
  rasi = input()
  degree = input()
  if(rasi in RasiDegree.keys()):
      return RasiDegree[rasi]+int(degree)
```

Comment: SunTaurus5°28’ 
Moon Capricorn25°10’
MercuryAries11°57’
VenusAries6°26’ 
MarsGemini16°55’
JupiterSagittarius23°59’
SaturnCapricorn20°30
UranusTaurus2°42’ 
NeptunePisces17°53’ 
PlutoCapricorn23°09’
The above are the longitudes of planets for a particular day.Is there a way to convert them into 360 format instead of individually inputting?

Comment: Can you give example? It means can you calculate for SunTaurus5°28’ Moon Capricorn25°10’?